# Log return code of request using flask using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, flask

I want to log my return code for each request. 
For example:- 
   Stream-logs: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2019 05:41:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

File-logs: [2019-03-03 20:41:40,284] DEBUG [src.get:12] Successfully served 
              request, response-info: {}

I want to add response-code (In above case "200") to be added in file-logs too.

OR

Can I append stream logs into my file-logs? If yes, How?

Answer (score -1):

You should read about `logging` module:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html

Below is the bare minimum example as how to log response code in a file.

```
import requests
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()

# create a file on the desktop and store logs
file = logging.FileHandler('C:/users/User/Desktop/test.log')

formatter = logging.Formatter()
file.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file) 


# set level of debugging
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def visit_google():
    # Connect to google
    r = requests.get("https://www.google.com")

    # Check status_code
    status_code = r.status_code

    if status_code == 200:
        # Save status code along with the message
        logger.debug("Able to connect to google successfully. " + str(status_code))
    else:
        logger.debug("Unable to connect to google. " + str(status_code))

visit_google()
```

if you open test.log file on the desktop, you will see message logged along with the status code.